# How IPFS search files?

Tags: ipfs

In order to find the file in [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) network by its hash, we should ask the adjacent nodes - "Do you have the file with hash **H(F)**?" and if not, then they propagate the question further.

1. How IPFS resolve the issue in case of plurality of this kind of requests?
2. How IPFS search engine works?

Comment: The answer is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. IPFS is based on distributed netwotk each node are client/server so each nodes can create an request or respond an request.
2. i think you can see around DHT  : https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/1396

i hope it's helpfull for you

Answer (score 4):

The `findProvs` call will let you know if there are any current providers https://github.com/ipfs/interface-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/DHT.md#dhtfindprovs